# Toggling the mode-line

Tags: mode-line

I am using this function to toggle the mode-line display.  But it does not always function when I call it repeatedly.

```
(defvar-local ramona-mode-line-rflog nil)

(defun ramona-mode-line ()
  "TODO."
  (interactive)

  (setq-local mode-line-format
               (if ramona-mode-line-rflog
                   (setq mode-line-format ramona-mode-line-rflog)
                 (setq ramona-mode-line-rflog mode-line-format)
                 (setq mode-line-format nil))))
```

Comment: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2022-11/msg00699.html - that was part of the discussion arising from your question.

Comment: `force-mode-line-update` with the optional argument set to non-nil if so desired.

Comment: Still does not work when I call  `(force-mode-line-update t)` everytime I reset `mode-line-format`.

Comment: Did you add the resetting of `ramona-mode-line-rflog` back to `nil` as pointed out in the link I pointed you to above?

Comment: Could not find the actual message discussing it.

Comment: Have introduced it in the `if` clause using `progn`, but now there is no modeline,

Comment: So you are making changes  to your program and we are  supposed to follow along using your descriptions? This is one reason that this is **NOT A CONVERSATION SITE** - as I have mentioned before and repeatedly: ask your question, accept or not accept any answer, but when you modify your program, you are now asking a new question - so make it a new question.

Comment: And at the very least, click the link I provide and read the text **carefully**.

Answer (score 0):

Inasmuch as the variable `mode-line-format` is always buffer-local, it does not need to be set with `setq-local`.  Either the variable `ramona-mode-line-rflog` or the buffer-local value of `mode-line-format` should be compared to something that does not change, such as the `(default-value 'mode-line-format)`.  The default value of a buffer-local variable can be set with `setq-default`.

```lisp
(defvar-local ramona-mode-line-rflog "foo")

(defun ramona-mode-line ()
  "TODO."
  (interactive)
  (setq mode-line-format
          (if (equal mode-line-format (default-value 'mode-line-format))
             ramona-mode-line-rflog
           (default-value 'mode-line-format)))
  (force-mode-line-update))
```

Comment: Have resetted `ramona-mode-line-rflog` back to `nil`.  But the modeline is gone and never toggles.

Comment: Then `ramona-mode-line-rflog` is not needed.

Comment: Did you even try the suggested solution? Starting from `emacs -Q` - a clean slate so to speak? You are randomly combining bits and pieces from previous attempts with this answer: don't! Start with `emacs -Q`, copy the answer to the `*scratch*` buffer, evaluate the two expressions with `C-j` after the closing paren, then keep evaluating `(ramona-mode-line)`: it toggles between the default value and a mode line with just `foo` in it. Again, you are wasting everybody's time (and yours) by not reading carefully what people write and not following advice.

Comment: I know it will have but am asking if using the variable can be avoided and just have the function.